# ¿Existe algún término para "ordenador" y "computadora" que se entienda en todos los países?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, solicitud-de-término, español-neutral, informática

Ya vimos hace tiempo en [Difference between "computadora" and "ordenador"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2396/1674) que tanto *ordenador* como *computadora* y *computador* sirven para definir el mismo concepto.

Me gustaría ahora saber si existe algún término que se entienda bien en todos los países, especialmente para utilizarlo a la hora de traducir "software", que imagino se usará en todos los países hispanohablantes.

DPD nos dice en su artículo *computadora*:

> [**computador -ra**](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=XhHavdTb6D6iCeuEqA). ‘Máquina electrónica capaz de realizar un tratamiento automático de la información y de resolver con gran rapidez problemas matemáticos y lógicos mediante programas informáticos’. Estas formas son las usadas mayoritariamente en el español de América, por influjo del inglés computer. Según las zonas, existen distintas preferencias: en la mayoría de los países de América se prefiere el femenino *computadora*, mientras que el masculino *computador* es de uso mayoritario en Chile y Colombia. En España se usa preferentemente el término *ordenador*, tomado del francés ordinateur.

Por lo que tendríamos:

- computador → Chile y Colombia
- computadora → resto de países de América
- ordenador → España

[Google Trends al comparar ordenador, computador y computadora](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&q=ordenador,computador,computadora) muestra una tendencia que encaja con lo que dice el DPD, localizando el uso de estas palabras :

> [image]
>
> azul: ordenador
> rojo: computador
> amarillo: computadora

Efectivamente, en España es muy raro oír computador/a. ¿La gente sabrá a qué nos referimos?. Entiendo que ocurre lo opuesto en los países de Hispanoamérica.

Comment: Con "Efectivamente, en España es muy raro oír computador/a; la gente sabrá a qué nos referimos" parece que contestaste tu propia pregunta.

Comment: I am amused to see that in the UK we seem to call them _computadores_ at least according to Google

Comment: @mdewey well, I wouldn't take the info from non Spanish speaking countries very seriously. See how Mozambique and Angola also appear, probably because they are used in Portuguese.

Comment: I think the statistics refer to the *native* spanish-speaking persons who happen to dwell within her majesty's realms. Also of note, the U.S. is the country with the **fifth largest spanish-speaking population** in the world, barely behind Spain and Argentina. Mexico more than doubles in Spanish speakers both Colombia and Spain, 2nd and 3rd respectively. Cfr. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=native+spanish+speakers+by+country

Answer (score 9, accepted):

En España, lo de que resulte raro escuchar a alguien decir "computadora" es algo más bien reciente. En los 80 y 90 no era tan raro, de hecho me atrevería a decir que ambos términos estaban a la par (a pie de calle, al menos; desconozco el uso a nivel académico en aquella época). Desde finales de los 90 en adelante, sí que parece que se popularizó más el uso de "ordenador".

Si revisamos en [CORPES XXI](http://web.frl.es/CORPES/view/inicioExterno.view) las estadísticas actuales de aparición de los términos "ordenador", "computador", "computadora" en el lenguaje actual de América, tenemos:

- **ordenador**

  - Frecuencia absoluta: 1.162
  - Documentos: 689
  - Frecuencia normalizada: 4,69 casos por millón
  - Porcentaje dentro del grupo buscado: 11%
- **computador**

  - Frecuencia absoluta: 2.335
  - Documentos: 1.068
  - Frecuencia normalizada: 9,44 casos por millón
  - Porcentaje dentro del grupo buscado: 21%
- **computadora**

  - Frecuencia absoluta: 7.498
  - Documentos: 3.300
  - Frecuencia normalizada: 30,32 casos por millón
  - Porcentaje dentro del grupo buscado: 68%

Es decir, que "**computadora**" es con mucho el término más utilizado allí. Y en España se entiende perfectamente, se entendía hace 30 años y se entiende ahora.
Es cierto que en España puede sonar un poco a español sudamericano pero, englobado en un texto que no tenga voseo, ni ustedeo, ni otras construcciones típicas del español americano, sospecho que "computadora" apenas llamaría la atención. Sirva como ejemplo esta levísima alteración de un párrafo del [artículo de Wikipedia para "computadora"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computadora) (artículo que, por cierto, va alternando el uso de los tres términos sin un criterio claro):

> Desde el punto de vista funcional es una máquina que posee, al menos, una unidad central de procesamiento, una memoria principal y algún periférico o dispositivo de entrada y otro de salida. Los dispositivos de entrada permiten el ingreso de datos, la CPU se encarga de su procesamiento (operaciones aritmético-lógicas) y los dispositivos de salida los comunican a otros medios. Así, la computadora recibe datos, los procesa y emite la información resultante, que luego puede ser interpretada, almacenada, transmitida a otra máquina o dispositivo o sencillamente impresa; todo ello a criterio de un operador o usuario y bajo el control de un programa.

En mi opinión, el uso de "computadora" en dicho texto no lo hace parecer más de una región o de otra.

Por tanto, **puestos a elegir un solo término, yo escogería "computadora".**

Comment: Yo diría que en españa "computadora" es un término asociado a las viejas "computadoras" que ocupaban salas enteras, mientras que con la aparición de los PC el término paso a ser ordenador (tal vez como distinción entre los unos y los otros). Obviamente el término "computadora" se entiende en España, al igual que "ordenador" creo que se entiende en otros paises. Pero no resulta natural en España, y de ahí que se busque algún termino mas neutral.

Comment: @yotanka yo hablo a nivel general. Si nos ponemos específicos al ámbito profesional informático si es cierto que "computador" (mas que computadora creo yo) está algo más extendido. Recuerdo una asignatura en la carrera: "Estructura y tecnología de Computadores"... Pero a nivel de "calle", absolutamente nadie en España habla de "computadores"

Comment: El DLE, como hemos visto en el ejemplo de Pikoh y en el de yotanka, usa *computadora* en sus definiciones, así que es una buena opción si tenemos que elegir entre esas opciones, *equipo* también me gusta para un contexto en el que se sobreentienda

Comment: El CORPES XXI es lo que le falta al corpus castellano 1800-2000 del explorador de n-gramas de google. Ahí podemos ver una tendencia iniciada en los 80 por sustituir computador(a) por el término más amplio "equipo de cómputo" a finales de los 90 es clara la tendencia a ala baja del uso de este término en favor de un creciente uso de el segundo, como mebciono en mi respuesta...  Extrapolando se podría pensar que en los 30s o 40s de este siglo el término prevalente sea *equipo de cómputo* Es posible usar el explorador de n-gramas o alguna herramienta similar para comprobar esto?

Comment: Lo ideal sería el CORPES XXI (mmmm datos duros) creo que para validar tu excelente respuesta hay que explorar el detalle de sustitución que observé en la frecuencia de uso de computadora vs equipo de cómputo. La atricion del primero vs el segundo es más que clara entre 1990 y 2000

Answer (score 7):

Yo propondría *equipo* como un término neutral para definir un ordenador/computador/a. Creo que es comprensible en todos los paises, y de hecho la RAE [recoge esta acepción](http://dle.rae.es/?id=G09HIAP) como:

> 5. m. Inform. Conjunto de aparatos constituido por una computadora y sus periféricos.

Comment: ¿Y seguro que no nos dirán desde Hispanoamérica que allí usan _team_? :P

Comment: Y por supuesto, ¡bienvenido a [spanish.se]!

Comment: @fedorqui para nada estoy seguro. Por eso _propongo_ y no _aseguro_ ;) Y gracias por la bienvenida.

Comment: @walen en la pregunta no está explicado, pero esta ha surgido del proceso de traducción que estamos llevando acabo en [es.so]. Así que el contexto en el caso que nosotros buscábamos está bien definido :)

Comment: @fedorqui 1) Aporto con que _equipo_ se entiende al menos en Chile. 2) Creo que es el término que usa la traducción de Windows para Latinoamérica, lo que lo haría reconocible en toda la región. 3) El equivalente en inglés sería _system_ (sé que lo de _team_ era una humorada, pero lo dejo como antecedente).

Comment: al menos en Colombia también se aplica el término *equipo* para un computador, así que al menos se cuenta para 3 países (Co, Ch y Es). En algunas páginas (la de HP de México, por ej) se usa también el término, así que sería confirmar con usuarios o páginas que confirmen su *universalidad* hispanoamericana (aunque se deja de lado a Guinea Ecuatorial...)

Comment: La tendencia de uso en "equipo de cómputo" va a la alza, a costa de incidencias del uso de "computador" es decir, efectivamente hay una tendencia estadística clara en que "equipo de cómputo" es preferible. Cfr la gráfica generada del explorador de n-gramas de google, allá abajo ejvmj respuesta. Mi voto va en esta respuestas. De @Pikoh (si gustas incluye mi gráfica en tu respuesta y borro la mía que se estanco en 0 antes de abundar en la estadística. )

Comment: @hlecuanda creo que tu respuesta está bien como está. Es una respuesta muy completa y bien argumentada :)

Answer (score 3):

Al final los dos terminos se entienden tanto en América como en España, lo único que pasará es que si dices "computador" o "computadora" en España, sabrán que eres latinoamericano, y si dices "ordenador" en América latina, sabrán que eres español.

Comment: Sí, lo mismo creo yo.

Answer (score 2):

La culpable es IBM y su departamento de mercadotecnia, de acuerdo a [Fundeu](https://www.fundeu.es/noticia/reflexiones-en-torno-a-los-vocablos-computador-y-ordenador-5004/) y al [autor](http://www.apuntesonline.org/art.vol4no4.computadorauordenadorok.htm) que hace referencia en estos dos articulos:

> Resulta que la culpable de toda la polémica no es otra que la IBM,
>   empresa que por razones históricas nunca ha sido muy partidaria, ni
>   siquiera en inglés, de la denominación computer, empleada
>   universalmente por sus competidores. [...]
>
> La contienda entre "computador " y "ordenador" duró unos años en España, pero **la influencia decisiva en favor del último término se debió nuevamente a
>   la IBM, que en sus libros de instrucciones y manuales técnicos para
>   España, así como en sus programas y clases de capacitación para
>   usuarios y técnicos** (según me han contado quienes asistieron a ellas),
>   **recomendaba, cuando no exigía, el uso exclusivo de "ordenador"**. Al
>   desapego histórico de IBM por computer (término usado por su empresa
>   predecesora y por la competencia) se unió ahora la posibilidad
>   comercial de presentar sus máquinas como cosas distintas ("mejores")
>   que los computers ofrecidos por sus competidores.
>
> Los partidarios de "ordenador" alegan que "computador" no es apropiado
>   porque estas máquinas, además de hacer cómputos numéricos, llevan a
>   cabo operaciones lógicas y de ordenamiento de datos de diversas
>   clases.
>
> Pero Francia, y sobre todo España, han adoptado el nombre que les empapuzó una empresa norteamericana, la misma que nunca pudo convencer a sus compatriotas de que llamasen a estas máquinas algo parecido a lo que hoy las llaman franceses y españoles.

Concuerda con todos los grafos y análisis mostrados en las otras respuestas, debido a su popularidad en los años 90, y su asentamiento entro los usuarios finales entre 1980 y 1990.

Si antes era valido, porque computadora no puede serlo ahora?

Cuando en nuestro escritorio vemos el icono de 'Mi PC' diriamos 'Mi Computadora Personal'.

Comment: Interesante, lo curioso es que el término PC (Personal Computer) también fue cosa IBM cuando nombro así a una de sus maquinas en los 80.

Comment: Muy interesantes datos! Tienen un sorprendente paralelismo con el caso de los ***paquetes de software*** concepto usado incluso en inglés. Sin embargo **Steve Jobs** desde la introducción del iPhone se avoco a sustituir este vocablo por su consentido **app** supuestamente de *application* o *software aplicativo* (vs software de sistema). Pero la genialidad de Jobs buscaba relacionar los ***apps*** con su compañía, ***App*le**. (The app company fue su lema brevemente). Claro, necesitas una *Mac* de *Apple* para usar los mejores *apps*. Si no, solo son programas comunes y corrientes.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que la forma más genérica y universalmente entendible podría ser

> ### Equipo de cómputo

O en su caso más aséptico

> ### Dispositivo de cómputo

Que hábilmente abarca desde móviles hasta supercomputadoras, todos son dispositivos y para todos su función escencial es el cómputo.

Claro que es como decir " **Está noche cenaré un rico plato de *Phaseolus vulgaris* de la olla** ". Pero si no se le llama así, nunca terminaremos de entender si son habichuelas guisantes o humildes frijolitos.

---

**Edit**

En estos casos, la respuesta correcta generalmente es elusiva pues se puede caer en la tentacion de ignorar los contextos sintácticos para favorecer el término regional que nos parece más familiar; considerando *rarísimas* cualquiera de las alternativas. Es entonces que fieles a el *Zeitgeist* o espíritu de los tiempos debamos referirnos a la *fuente de la verdad* en otras palabras: **datos duros**

[image: explorador de n-gramas de google]

Una [consulta al explorador de n-gramas](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Computadora%2Ccomputador%2Cequipo%20de%20c%C3%B3mputo%2Cordenador&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CComputadora%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcomputadora%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BComputadora%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCOMPUTADORA%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ccomputador%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcomputador%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BComputador%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCOMPUTADOR%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cequipo%20de%20c%C3%B3mputo%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bequipo%20de%20c%C3%B3mputo%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BEquipo%20de%20c%C3%B3mputo%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BEquipo%20de%20C%C3%B3mputo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cordenador%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bordenador%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BOrdenador%3B%2Cc0) de google nos permite visualizar la incidencia de cada término en el *corpus castellano de publicaciones 1800-2000* y las conclusiones, a reserva de la inclusión en el corpus de las publicaciones 2000-2015 son las siguientes:

A) claramente el término de preferencia para publicaciones impresas es *computadora* o *computador* a partir de 1960 aparece este término, coincidiendo con el inicio de la era digital, y sumando las incidencias podemos ver que se usa con aproximadamente el doble de frecuencia que *ordenador*. Hay que resaltar que el *corpus castellano* tiene un sesgo hacia la usanza insular del idioma, aún así claramente el término más frecuentemente utilizado en publicaciones no es *ordenador*

B) *ordenador* es un término **reapropiado**, es imposible que entre 1800 y 1910 al menos, se usara para describir *equipos de cómputo programables electrónico digitales*

C) a partir de 1980 se empieza a utilizar el neologismo **equipo de cómputo** sin duda, como un esfuerzo de los editores de ambos lados del Atlántico por encontrar un término universal y salvar la brecha con un concepto más neutral que computador(a) vs ordenador.

***Equipo de cómputo* claramente empieza a sustituir *computador(a)*** pues sus incidencias incrementan a costa de una disminución en la frecuencia del uso de *computador(a)*. Dada la prevalencia de este término sobre ordenador desde los 60s, es muy probable que en las próximas décadas sea el término de preferencia para el castellano escrito formal. Es imposible -sin embargo- sostener esta especulación sin los datos del corpus castellano 2000-2015

D) siendo rigoristas, el **ordenamiento de datos** es solamente *una clase de operaciones de cómputo* que los equipos modernos pueden realizar. Si deseamos un término que describa las funciones que desempeñan esta clase de equipos, (electrónico digitales programables) *ordenador* sería claramente un **arcaicismo**

Comment: Uno no pide un plato de *Fabaceae Phaseolus Phaseolus Vulgaris y Angiospermis Plantar Oriza Sativa* Se pide un plato de **Moros y cristianos*. **Exste un contexto** que nos permite **obviar** toda la filiación excepto la especie. Aquí el contexto es ***"Dispositivos de cómputo programables electrónico digitales.***" Aún que la *regla de cálculo* es un *dispositivo*, y se usa para el *cómputo*, nadie confundiria una regla de cálculo con un dispositivo de cómputo en el contexto que hablamos. Igual distinguimos entre el arroz y las pepitas de girasol y ambas son angiospermas! Rigorismo sintáctico

Comment: *Equipo de cómputo* a mi me suena rarísimo, más que un ordenador personal pensaría que es una máquina destinada a hacer cáculos

Comment: @yotanka someto mis conclusiones al rigor de los datos duros. Dicho sea de paso, esos mismos datos duros solo sostienen marginalmente mi respuesta; la usanza prevalente en castellano es Computador(a) desde los 60s, y ordenador es un término reapropiado, mientras que **equipo de cómputo** surge desde los 80's como alternativa neutra para salvar la brecha atlántica.

Comment: Sigo diciendo que suena raro, al menos en España. *Cómputo* es una palabra que se usa muy poco por aquí, creo que prácticamente solo la he oído cuando se cuentan votos y cosas así: «Se ha hecho el cómputo de votos». Si buscamos "equipo de cómputo" en Google Trends todos los resultados son de México. No creo que sea un  término tan neutral.

Comment: Checa el explorador de n-gramas, no miente. Es en verdad asombroso que hoy día podamos acceder instantáneamente a la frecuencia de uso de grupos de vocablos en publicaciones impresas de casi dos siglos en evolución del lenguaje ... Las tendencias ahí no dejan lugar a dudas: ubo un momento en los. 70s después de la introducción de equipos de cómputo electrónico digitales programables al mercado en que computador(a) y ordenador  usaron con la misma frecuencia. Desde entonces casi es el doble de publicaciones impresas eje usan el primer término. En los 90s se empieza a sustituir por eq de cómputo

Comment: ¿Se puede filtrar por países?

Comment: ¿Puedo preguntar una razón concreta para cambiar el parámetro "suavizado" de 3 a 0? ¿Por qué 0 y no 2 o 5? En tu opinión, ¿es puramente estético? ¿o sirve para un propósito en el gran esquema del análisis de estos datos?

Comment: deberías haber puesto @walen para que le llegue la notificación, en teoría si escribes bajo su comentario le debería avisar pero por alguna razón no siempre ocurre

Answer (score 1):

Yo aporto otra opción, que engloba todas las partes y componentes, y que pienso que no tendría ningún problema entre los diferentes países:

> **Sistema informático**

Aunque aún no está sancionada por el diccionario de la Academia, es de amplio uso.

El *Diccionario panhispánico del español jurídico* si lo contempla:

> **sistema informático**. Dispositivo aislado o conjunto de dispositivos interconectados o relacionados entre sí, cuya función, o la de alguno de sus elementos, sea el tratamiento automatizado de datos en ejecución de un programa (Convenio sobre Cibercriminalidad del Consejo de Europa, suscrito en Budapest el 23 de noviembre de 2001).