# ¿Cómo puede traducirse "push" en el ámbito de la programación?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, informática

Acabo de ver [una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/207801/83) en el Stack Overflow en español cuyo título es:

> Como **pushear** datos en un array vacio cada que vez que una funcion en disparada
>
> [image: Como "pushear" datos en un array vacío ...]

Pushear es obviamente una mala traducción. Para quienes no lo sepan, el método `push` se utiliza para añadir un  elemento **al final** de un `array`.

Mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo traducir `push` en el ámbito de la programación? Palabras cómo `añadir` o `agregar` no son lo bastante exactas, mientras que palabras como "pushear" son una mala traducción.

Comment: Para un array, yo usaría _añadir_ o _insertar_, pero si fuera el "push" que se hace en git, por ejemplo, usaría "subir".

Comment: I would have said there were distinct meaning of push in programming. If you have a stack you push a new item onto it and you pop an item off it. If you are talking about the flow of information you push something to someone as an alternative to them having to pull it from you. So e-mail is a push system, Twitter a pull one. Can you give a link to the question on SO in Spanish?

Comment: Thank you @murderofcrows unfortunately I do not speak javascript so not sure what it is doing but it looks like a stack is being used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Coincido con @murderofcrows en que probablemente la pregunta a la que te refieres es [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/207801/como-pushear-datos-en-un-array-vacio-cada-que-vez-que-una-funcion-en-disparada)

Sin ánimo de ofender a la persona que hacía la pregunta original, a mí el título me parece un engendro. "*Como pushear datos en un array vacio cada que vez que una funcion en disparada*".

Pero retomando el hilo de tu pregunta, la operación **push** se aplica sobre tipos abstractos de datos LIFO - Last In, First Out (Último dentro, primero fuera) -, comúnmente conocidos como **pilas** en castellano y stack en inglés. Las operaciones que puedes hacer sobre una pila son push y pop, que normalmente se traducen acertadamente como **apilar** y desapilar.

No son operaciones que normalmente se hagan sobre un **array**, tipo de datos que no tiene una traducción universal al castellano al contrario que pila. He llegado a leerlo como "arreglo". Yo lo traduciría como **casillero**, en cuanto que es un conjunto de casillas numeradas que pueden contener objetos.

La operación que se usa para poner objetos en una casilla o posición del array es la **asignación**. Se asigna un objeto a una posición determinada. Podrías emplear **insertar** también, pero no refleja fielmente lo que ocurre realmente, pues no se suelen emplear métodos put/insert sobre los arrays.

En el ejemplo, no se está haciendo la asignación directamente, se está empleando una envoltura (wrapper) que simula el comportamiento de una pila sobre un array, de forma que el programador se despreocupe de la gestión de posiciones del array. Por eso se emplea el método **push**. La acción no es pushear ni empujar ni nada parecido, la acción correcta es **invocar el método push**. El método se llama exactamente así "push", no es posible traducirlo al castellano porque no hay ningún método pushear ni apilar en ningún sitio.

Si el método se llamara *pushAtTheEnd*, los ingleses no usarían la expresión "do the pushAtTheEnding" o "execute the pushAtTheEnding", sino "invoke the method pushAtTheEnd".

Por último, las funciones se invocan, son los eventos los que se lanzan o disparan. Otra más de las traducciones incorrectas que aparecen en título y texto originales.

En el mundo de la programación, yo recomendaría aprender inglés antes que intentar traducir al castellano. Los lenguajes de programación tienen definidos sus objetos y métodos en inglés; la mayoría de la bibliografía, física y on-line, está en inglés; la mayoría de programadores e ingenieros es capaz de comunicarse en inglés y el mejor sitio para resolver dudas, el StackOverflow original y primigenio, está en inglés.

Comment: Sigo creyendo que tenemos que intentar a traducir al castellano, y creo que es posible hacerlo con una cierta elegancia.

Comment: @enxaneta Es que es un campo bastante dificil. ¿Cómo traducirías "array", por ejemplo? Me parece bien que se intente traducir procedimientos y metodologías, pero no ciertas cosas como nombres propios de objetos y métodos. En algún libro de programación web tradujeron los nombres de las clases java core de ese módulo como HttpRequest y ya no se podían hacer los ejemplos.

Comment: Reconozco que `array` no lo traduzco nunca, y los nombres de objetos y métodos tampoco. Es más cada vez que traduzco una cosa pruebo poner entre paréntesis el nombre utilizado en inglés. Tienes razón. Ës un campo difícil.

Answer (score 3):

Ya hay una respuesta aceptada.  Lo que sigue es detalle.

Para dar un poco de contexto histórico a las operaciones de PUSH y POP, conviene referir a los procesadores PDP-6 y PDP-10 de la empresa digital de los EEUU.  La PDP-6, introducida en 1963 y la PDP-10 introducida en 1968, fueron unas de las primeras máquinas con operaciones de PUSH y POP entre su juego de instrucciones.

[Descripción en Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-6)

Las operaciones de PUSH y POP operaban sobre un vector (array) utilizando un puntero de pila en un acumulador para localizar el extremo de una pila.  Pero en idioma de MACRO-10 había que reservar el espacio para la pila como si fuera un vector (array).  Yo diría que era un vector utilizada como una pila.

En [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_(inform%C3%A1tica)), la palabra "vector" se define como "matriz unidimensional".  Me parece que esto es un "array".

Si se entiende las operaciones como verbos, "push" y "pop" vienen a ser "apilar" y "desapilar".  En la respuesta aceptada, éstos se llaman métodos en vez de operaciones.  Esto se introdujo cuando se inventó la programación orientada en objetos.

Entre 1975 y 1978, yo dicté cursillos de MACRO-10 en Bolivia y Venezuela para la empresa digital y sus clientes.  Lamento decir que los estudiantes y yo utilizábamos "spanglish" con abandono.  Las materias escritas estaban todas en inglés.

Me parece que la programación está bastante ligada al inglés por razones históricas.  Pero la informática no.  Hay palabras castellanas para todos los conceptos de la informática.  Es cuestión de aprenderlas.  Lamento decir que yo no las he aprendido.

Comment: ¡¡Fantástica respuesta con gran fondo histórico!! Y qué bueno seria leer tus impresiones personales sobre tu experiencia en [¿Existe algún término para “ordenador” y “computadora” que se entienda en todos los países?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/25781/1674)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias gracias por su respuesta!

Comment: Mis impresiones personales ya son antiguas, de 1975 hasta 1989.  Y se limitan a Bolivia, Venezuela, México, y Puerto Rico.  La palabra "computadora" se entendía en todos eso lugares y en aquella época.  En el presente y en los demás países, yo no sabría decir.

Comment: La primera vez que usé la palabra "computadora" había alguien con nombre Dora presente.  No es necesario repetir los chistes que resultaron.

Comment: Gran aporte, sin duda. Entre las múltiples traducciones de "array" conocía la de "vector" que apuntas. La cual no tiene mucho sentido y desconozco su origen, ya que un array no es un vector como se entiende comúnmente en el ámbito ciéntifico, un segmento de línea con dirección y sentido. Quizás la más adecuada sea matriz, que también apuntas pero nótese que la palabra inglesa matrix no es la que se emplea para nombrar la estructura de datos array, de ahí que no suela traducirse como tal tampoco.

Comment: Respecto a la distinción que haces entre programación e informática, quizás tengas razón y al explicar los tipos abstractos de datos en la segunda, se puedan nombrar las estructuras en español pero ten en cuenta que la pregunta original viene de StackOverflow Español, un sitio sobre programación. Insisto en que los lenguajes de programación están definidos en inglés y es en inglés donde el que preguntaba podría obtener más y mejor ayuda para resolver sus problemas.

Comment: En la definición de la etiqueta [array] en Stackoverflow Español, usan la palabra "vector" para explicar un array.  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array

Comment: Tal vez la frase "matriz unidimensional" sería la más adecuada.  Pero es un poco largo, y a los programadores les gusta las cosas en breve.

Comment: @WalterMitty la palabra **array** en Colombia se acostumbra a traducir por **arreglo**. No se usa ni es aconsejable **vector** ya que por definición implica que es de 1 (una) sola dimensión y es posible que un **array** sea multidimensional.

Answer (score 1):

No se traduce, normalmente. Si te pones en site:.es [España] + programación sale un montón de:hacer push o hacer pull.

**Traducciones posibles para** *push data to an array*:

- añadir datos en un array con el método push
- usar push para añadir dados a un array
- hacer push de los dados al array

Seguramente, habrá otras también.

Son solo posibilidades. La informática es una especialidad y el español utiliza los términos del inglés directamente o de manera modificada.

Se ve, por ejemplo, una explicación sobre JavaScript en el siguiente texto:

> [Ejemplos de que es y como usar push en un ARRAY en javascript](http://www.videotutoriales.es/video-tutoriales-gratis-espanol-online/ejemplo-que-es-como-usar-push-array-javascript/)
>
> el método **push** permite añadir un elemento al final de un array
>
> Como puedes ver en el siguiente ejemplo he creado una función que se llama mifuncion que se ejecuta al pulsar en el botón

Y [en otro sitio](http://alesanderlopez.es/git-y-github/):

> Pues cuando hagamos **push** puede fallarnos, por lo que siempre antes de hacer un push debemos hacer un pull para tener siempre los ultimos cambios antes de subir los nuestros. [del sitio escrito por un programador en España]

Claro, push es empujar. A veces se puede poner este verbo.  También sale PUSH como comando.

También vi: apilar o empujar (para push a stack) en una [tesis](http://personales.unican.es/pardol/Docencia/ComputComplex.pdf). Esta tesis trata a fondo de esta pregunta y también dice:

> push: Apilar (empujar) una pila encima de otra.

O en [JavaScript arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp):

> array: en Javascript, es un ejemplo del uso del término array
>
> What is an Array?
>   **An array is a special variable, which can hold more than one value at a time.**
>   If you have a list of items (a list of car names, for example), storing the cars in single variables could look like this:
>   [...]An array can hold many values under a single name, and you can access the values by referring to an index number.

Aquí tenemos la explicación en español: [arrays explicado en español](http://www.sc.ehu.es/sbweb/fisica/cursoJava/fundamentos/clases1/arays.htm)

> Un array es un medio de guardar un conjunto de objetos de la misma clase. Se accede a cada elemento individual del array mediante un número entero denominado índice. 0 es el índice del primer elemento y n-1 es el índice del último elemento, siendo n, la dimensión del array. Los arrays son objetos en Java y como tales vamos a ver los pasos que hemos de seguir para usarlos convenientemente
>
> - Declarar el array
> - Crear el array
> - Inicializar los elementos del array
> - Usar el array.

Yo soy traductora en estos temas. Claro, solo hacia el inglés. Hacer push se ve mucho.

[Los enlaces dan las referencias de los autores]

Comment: sí, nunca oí nada que no fuera _pull_ o _push_ al trabajar con Git.

Comment: Gracias a los que hicieran desaparecer los números negativos. :)